# Displaying 3 images at a time

Tags: jquery

I would like to display 3 images at a time from a box containing 10-12 images. I already have this script which displays one image at a time, but how can it be changed to rotate 3 (or another amount) at a time infinitely?
I have been trying to use `slice()` instead of `eq()` but I can't make it go forward by 3...

Js:

```
function displayImg() {
  // Each item
  var item = $('.image');

  //initial fade-in time
  var initialFadeIn = 1000;

  //interval between items
  var itemInterval = 3000;

  //cross-fade time
  var fadeTime = 1000;

  //count number of items
  var numberOfItems = item.length;

  //set current item
  var currentItem = 0;

  //show first item
  item.eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

  //loop through the items
  var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function() {
    item.eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

    if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
      currentItem = 0;
    } else {
      currentItem++;
    }
    item.eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

  }, itemInterval);
}

displayImg();
```

Markup:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="image">one</div>
  <div class="image">two</div>
  <div class="image">three</div>
  <div class="image">four</div>
  <div class="image">five</div>
  <div class="image">six</div>
  <div class="image">Seven</div>
  <div class="image">Eight</div>
  <div class="image">Nine</div>
  <div class="image">Ten</div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UBpqT/171/).

Comment: You can wrap desired number of images (even dinamically) in containers, and target containers, so var item = $('.container');... It would be easiest solution, i guess, without too much changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using splice function.

No changes to your html

Js (I have done it with show/hide):

```
   function displayImg() {
  // Each item
  var item = $('.image');

  //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
  var initialFadeIn = 1000;

  //interval between items (in milliseconds)
  var itemInterval = 3000;

  //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
  var fadeTime = 1000;

  //count number of items
  var numberOfItems = item.length;

  //set current item
  var currentItem = 0;
  var noOfItems=3;
  var totalItems=10;

  item.slice(currentItem, noOfItems).show()

   var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function() {
    item.slice(currentItem, noOfItems).hide()
    if(currentItem<=totalItems)
    {
        currentItem=noOfItems;
      noOfItems+=3;
    }
    else
    {
        currentItem=0;
      noOfItems=3
    }  
    item.slice(currentItem, noOfItems).show();
  }, itemInterval);
}

displayImg();
```

CSS:

```
    .image {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to achieve. Pretty cool. Thanks.